# python regular expression repeating pattern matching entire string

Tags: python, regex

I am working with python regular expression basics .I have a string

> **start***abcsd***end***sff***start***sdfsdf***end***s***start***dfsf***end**.

How do i get the strings in between consecutive  **start** and **end** without matching the entire string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `start.*?end` in the re. The question mark means "as few as possible".

Comment: Almost - just needs a capture group adding to exclude the terminators from the result group `start(.*?)end`

Comment: This answer should be correct. For further googling needs, you should search of "greedy" vs "non-greedy" regular expressions.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = "startabcsdendsffstartsdfsdfendsstartdfsfend."
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('start(.*?)end')
>>> p.findall(s)
['abcsd', 'sdfsdf', 'dfsf']
```